# MySQL search query is not executing in Postgres DB

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In MySQL the below query is executing properly.

```
SELECT * FROM <Table-name> WHERE (Table.ID LIKE '1%')
```

But when I try to execute the above query in Postgres, I get the following exception

> "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   integer ~~ unknown Hint: No operator matches the given name and
>   argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts".

If I convert the same query

```
SELECT * 
FROM <Table-name> 
WHERE CAST(Table.ID as TEXT) LIKE '1%'
```

This gets executed directly in Postgres DB. But I need some query which implicitly type cast in DB, which allows me to execute the MySQL query without any exception. Because I remember there is a way for integer to boolean implicit type cast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: As far as I can tell implicit casts were removed in PostgreSQL 8.3. What version are you on?

Comment: It those are really numbers, searching with `LIKE` does not make sense. If those aren't "real" numbers than store them in a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 2):

If you search this site with `[postgresql] explicit type casts` you will get enough information to solve your problem.